# Populating razor text input from ViewData

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor, mvvm

Im trying to pre populate an input text box in a modal. Currently i click the edit button which calls a jQuery function that makes an ajax call

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".selectRow").click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var row = $(this).closest("tr"),      
                tds = row.find("td:nth-child(1)").first();

            var textval = tds.text();

            $.ajax({
                    url: "EditApplication?handler=GetRowInfo",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { textval },
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $('#editAppModal').modal('show');
                    },
                    failure: function () {
                        alert("failure");
                    }
                })
        });
    });
</script>
```

On completion i show the modal. This jQuery function calls a method in the code behind called `GetRowInfo` which grabs a cell from a table.

`GetRowInfo`

```
        public void OnPostGetRowInfo(string textval)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------"+textval);

            DutyWeb dutyWebManager = new DutyWeb();

            textval = textval.Trim();

            Console.WriteLine("-----------------NEW-"+textval);
            selectedRow = dutyWebManager.SearchByApplication(textval);

            ViewData["appName"] = textval;

        }
```

I assign the text value sent into the ViewData as appName

I then assign the textbox input value to be the ViewData["appName"

```
<div class="modal-body">
          <input type="text" name="appName" id="appName" value='@ViewData["appName"]'>
          <input type="text" name="appShortName" style="width:15%">
          <br>
      </div>
```

I dont know if im doing this wrong but it seems right to me. The modal is inside of a form element. Stepping through revealed that the ViewData is indeed storing the correct value, but its not being displayed in the textbox

I would like to avoid using jQuery to do this. I feel like ViewData is a much easier way of accomplishing the same task

Comment: The problem is that the view is never being updated.  `ViewData` might be storing the correct value but you never use it.  So, you'd need to use jQuery (easier, you've already done the harder part) to update the textbox, or use a partial view to re-render the view with the updated value.

Comment: Gah you're right! Cant believe i never thought of that. So setting the texbox val is probably the best way to approach this?

Comment: Yeah, I'd just make `OnPostGetRowInfo` return json for the new text value, then you can update the textbox value in the `success` function of the ajax call.  Do you even need to post data? You could just update the textbox using jQuery